# "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logs.user_ID' in 'on clause'" - when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I try to run SQL query and get error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logs.user_ID' in 'on clause'
```

Query goes like this:

```
SELECT 
logs.*, users.first_Name, users.last_Name, users.middle_Name 
FROM logs 
LEFT JOIN users ON (logs.user_ID = users.ID) 
WHERE logs.record_Type = 'issues' AND logs.record_ID = 33
```

When I run query manually on server it returns correct result, but in PHP code no joy.

When I remove "WHERE" conditions it runs just fine inside PHP. At this point I suspect that is MySQL syntax issue, but I can't figure it out.

Code for query generation:

```
public static function prepareQuery()   {

if(self::$distinct) {
    $query = array("SELECT DISTINCT");
} else {
    $query = array("SELECT");
}


if (count(self::$_fields) == 0) {
    $query[] = "*";
} else {
    $query[] = implode(", ", self::$_fields);
}

if (!empty(self::$_table)) {
    $query[] = "FROM " . self::$_table;
}

if (!empty(self::$_join)) {
    foreach (self::$_join as $aJoin) {
        list($table, $field, $expression, $value) = $aJoin;
        $sJoin = "LEFT JOIN " . $table . " ON (" . $field . " " . $expression . " " . $value . ")";
        $aJoins[] = $sJoin;
    }
    $query[] = implode(" \n", $aJoins);
}

if (!is_null(self::$_expression)) {
    $query[] = "WHERE " . self::$_expression;
}

self::$_query = implode(" \n", $query);
self::reset();
}
```

Here me calling that method:

```
public static function get($recordType = "all", $recordID = "0", $userID = "0") {
Select::setTable("logs");

$aFields = array("logs.*", "users.first_Name", "users.last_Name", "users.middle_Name");
Select::addField($aFields);

if ($recordType != "all") {
    Select::customExpression("logs.record_Type = '$recordType' AND logs.record_ID = $recordID");
} else {
    if ($userID != "0") {
        Select::customExpression("logs.user_ID = $userID");
    }
}

Select::join("users", "logs.user_ID", "=", "users.ID");

Select::prepareQuery();

Str::print_var(Select::$_query);

Select::execute();

$oResult = Select::$result;
return $oResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Log");
}
```

Comment: can you add your php code or query variable code

Comment: Can you add the sql code of the actual query created in PHP?

Comment: I don't know why you have parentheses around your `ON` clause, but in any case, it looks like the parser accepted it.  But this will be hard to answer then, because your query looks like completely valid raw MySQL to me.

Comment: Giorgius: This is actual query generated by php. I will try to add the code but it is pretty complicated :)

Comment: You are probaly using two different DBs.

Comment: Tim: Parenthesis I added because saw some comments here on similar post.

Comment: Paul: No, I'm not. :)

Comment: Execute the following in PHP: `SHOW CREATE TABLE logs` - And post the result.

Comment: Paul: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_Type` text NOT NULL,
  `record_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activity` text NOT NULL,
  `activity_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: "Query goes like this" - You should post the exact query that is created. After `self::$_query = implode(" \n", $query);` put `var_dump(self::$_query);`

Comment: Please post the full error message. It usually has the full query after that message.

Comment: Paul: yes, I did that. The query I posted is copy paste from page where I output query using var_dump(). uh, sorry, look at corrected post. Code for calling was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is not technically an answer, but I solved the problem. 
Generated SQL was:

```
SELECT 
logs.*, users.first_Name, users.last_Name, users.middle_Name 
FROM logs 
LEFT JOIN users ON logs.user_ID = users.ID 
WHERE logs.record_Type = 'issues' AND logs.record_ID = 33
```

I changed "ON" clause removing table reference from "logs.user_ID" and it worked just fine. When I run this SQL on server it highlighted word LOGs for me so I suspect that LOGS it is some special keyword. 
Although problem is solved, reason for that error is still mystery for me, so I would appreciate any input on this problem.